# Windows: dialog doesn't show icon given by RC-file

Tags: windows, winapi, dialog, icons

I have a weird problem with an icon in a dialog under Windows.

I define a dialog and icon in the `RC-file`. Below are the relevant lines:

```
define IDI_LOGO 102
ICON IDI_LOGO, IDC_ICON_LOGO, 440, 322, 21, 20
IDI_LOGO ICON "icon.ico"
```

Later I display the dialog and get a system icon displayed in the dialog instead of my own. However, if I run the following code, I get my icon displayed in the dialog:

```
HMODULE module = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
HICON icon = LoadIcon(module, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_LOGO));
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(dlg, IDC_ICON_LOGO), STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_ICON, (LPARAM)icon);
```

I use `MSVC2010 Express` (please do not ask why).

What is going wrong? Why the icon is not displayed as expected? Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Do error check for result of `LoadIcon` and check `GetLastError()` on failure.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani read that more carefully: the manual `LoadIcon()` way is working, but the version in the DIALOG definition in the resource file (the second line of the first snippet) does not.

Comment: I'm not sure; does the ICON statement let you use a numeric ID instead of a string literal name? [MSDN doesn't say...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381017%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I would hope that it does...

Comment: @HansPassant he says his code works; he's asking why his rc file alone does not. Should I go and edit it to make it more clear? Or am I the only one reading it wrong and everyone else is reading it correctly?

Comment: @andlabs He doesn't say *"his code works"* That's your interpretation. He asks *"what is going on?"* and *"Why the icon is not displayed as expected?"* It's not clear which part works and which part doesn't. I don't even know if it is talking about title bar icons or static controls. What is a "system icon"? The question has already been edited. Feel free to reverse the edits or to make any improvements

Comment: Here's how I read it: "[When] I display the dialog[, I] get a system icon [possibly IDI_APPLICATION but without a screenshot we can't know for sure] in the dialog instead of my own [which I thought I defined in the rc file by saying `ICON IDI_LOGO, IDC_ICON_LOGO`]. However, if I [add] the following code [which uses `SendMessage()` to set the icon], I get my icon displayed in the dialog [which is the correct output == this code works]. Why the icon is not displayed as expected [with just the rc file as I have it, and why do I need the `SendMessage()` call]?". Can @Bambur confirm this?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: OK, here it is again. I want to display a static icon in the dialog. I use MSVC2010 Express for a number of reasons. It does not include the resource editor. I make my own RC-file where I define the dialog and icon. Please see the lines I posted in the original question. Now, when I display the dialog, I get one of the system icons displayed instead of my own defined by the RC. If I use the code LoadIcon+SendMessage, I get my icon displayed. It looks like Windows does not use my module, i.e. executable, to load the icon from, but one of the system libraries. Why?

Comment: @andlabs thanks for the point! It looks like it is possible to use a numeric ID: nameID Unique name or a 16-bit unsigned integer value identifying the resource (from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381018(v=vs.85).aspx)), but it is unclear about defining icons inside DIALOG statement. On the other hand, I can see it goes that way in my old projects done in MSVS6 for instance.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this. The thing was that I did not provide the module handle when displaying the dialog itself. When I do as follows I get the icon and bitmaps displayed properly without doing anything in run-time.

```
INT_PTR displayMainDialog() {
    HMODULE module = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    return DialogBox(module, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, (DLGPROC)dlgProc);
}
```

The first argument of DialogBox was NULL, but it must be a handle to the module. I think this way Windows knows where to fetch the icons and bitmaps for static controls in the dialog from.

Anyway, many thanks to all responded!